# How to adjust components and JTable in a JFrame dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When i try to hide the rows in a jTable, the jTable ScrollPanel need to adjust its size to remaining rows and, other components in the Frame also adjust to the change. i.e., there shouldn't be any space between the components and the jTable after hiding the table-rows..

ex: in microsoft excel, when we delete a row, the remaining rows will move upwards to fill the deleted row..

Please help me.. Thank you..

Edited: 
Used a model that extends AbstractTableModel. Used RowFilter to hide the rows. 
Problem is even when the rows disapper, the JScrollpane(where the JTable resides) wont get adjusted to the remaining rows..

Comment: Edited title; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: @Riduidel: i thought this question is related to surrounding components and not the table itself.. that's why i didn't mentioned anything about table.. Anyway if you are still not clear with that, tell me will post the code here..
And about caring the community. I do like this community and it helped me lot. I accepted some answers, but i cant accept answers that hasn't worked for me.. Anyway help me with some answer to this question.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to resize the scroll pane to the desired multiple of `getRowHeight()`. You can use `validate()` "to cause a `Container` to lay out its subcomponents again" or `pack()` to cause the  `Window` "to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to *hide* rows or *delete* rows?  You mention hiding rows in `JTable` but deleting them in Excel.